# Why is SharedArray not correct after operation?

Tags: parallel-processing, julia

I have the following simple code to understand using the `@distributed` command, as in the docs https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/parallel-computing/#Multi-Core-or-Distributed-Processing-1:

```
using Distributed
using SharedArrays
using DelimitedFiles

f(x) = x^2
t = collect(-1:0.001:1)
y = SharedArray{Float64}(size(t,1))

@distributed for i in 1:size(t,1)
    y[i] = f(t[i])
end

file = open("foo.dat", "w")
writedlm(file, [t, y])
close(file)
```

But when I open the file `data = readdlm("foo.dat")`, the `y` values are all zero. Interestingly enough, if I were running a Jupyter notebook, and the file write section,

```
file = open("foo.dat", "w")
writedlm(file, [t, y])
close(file)
```

was in a different cell, then the file contains the correct content. This is consistent in the REPL where running the data write commands works fine. Additionally, if the above code is in a script, the `foo.dat` file is also incorrect *unless* I have something before the `writedlm` command dealing with `y`. For example, having `println(y)` before `writedlm(file, [t, y])`, then `foo.dat` will contain the correct contents. Is there something I'm not doing right? It seems that there is *a* workaround by simply doing something with `y` before writing it to file, but it just seems like a weird bug and I'm wondering if anyone has any suggestions, or if this is something that should be brought up as an issue on GitHub.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The macro `@distributed` is launching the distributed computations asynchronously using green threads to control them. You should wait until they complete before processing further the data (e.g. writing to a file).

Hence your loop should look like this:

```
@sync @distributed for i in 1:size(t,1)
    y[i] = f(t[i])
end
```

Additionally, your code does not spawn any worker processes.
You could run for an example to add two workers:

```
addprocs(2)
```

But then you will notice that your `@distributed` loop crashes because your `f` function should be defined across all worker processes not just the master. Hence, your code should look like:

```
@everywhere f(x) = x^2
```

The above line should be *after* the `addprocs` command.

Happy distributed computing!